# Powershell v2 - Extracting Date from a dynamic string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a string like this:

> \aaaaaaaaa\bbbbb\ccccc\ffffffff20160506

The part before the date is dynamic, so I just can't do a replace or substring - that part can change in both content and number of characters.

Can you please advise how can I extract that date to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming that the date is always at the end of the string and in yyyyMMdd format:

```
$foo = "\aaaaaaaaa\bbbbb\ccccc\ffffffff20160506"
$datevar = $foo.substring($foo.length-8)
```

If you want to cast that string to a DateTime object you can use:

```
$datevar = [datetime]::ParseExact($datevar, "yyyyMMdd",$null)
```

Comment: Perfect. How do I get the rest of the string to another variable?

Comment: Untested, because I don't have Powershell at hand now: `$firstpart = $foo.substring(0,$foo.length-8)` You have to use the optional second parameter of substring to pass the length of the substring you want. It might be `-9`, you have to test it ;)

Answer (score 2):

I am not that into powershell but I guess you can do something like this,

Eventhough the string is dynamic the date part is exactly 8 characters right? So what if you get the full length and subtract 8 characters and get the substring from that index.

Example:

> string= \aaaaaaaaa\bbbbb\ccccc\DDDDD_yyyyMMdd length = 37 point=37-8 =
>   29
>
> subsctring(9,37)